# Issue with Haskell's "do"

Tags: haskell, syntax, monads

I wrote a Haskell function that calculates the factorial of every number in a given list and prints it to the screen.

```
factPrint list =
if null list
    then putStrLn ""
    else do putStrLn ((show.fact.head) list)
        factPrint (tail list)
```

The function works, but I find the third line a bit confusing.
Why hasn't the compiler(GHC) reported an error on it since there is no "do" before the "putStrLn" (quasi?)function? 
If I omit "do" from the 4th line, an error pops up as expected.

I'm quite new to Haskell and its ways, so please pardon me if I said something overly silly.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
do putStrLn ((show.fact.head) list)
   factPrint (tail list)
```

is actually another way of writing

```
putStrLn ((show.fact.head) list) >> factPrint (tail list)
```

which, in turn, means

```
putStrLn ((show.fact.head) list) >>= \_ -> factPrint (tail list)
```

The `do` notation is a convenient way of stringing these monads together, without this other ugly syntax.

If you only have one statement inside the `do`, then you are not stringing anything together, and the `do` is redundant.

Answer (score 5):

If you are new to Haskell, think of `do` as similar to required braces after `if` in a C-like language:

```
if (condition)
  printf("a"); // braces not required
else {
  printf("b"); // braces required
  finish();
}
```

`do` works the same way in Haskell.

---

Maybe it would help to look at the type of factPrint, and then refactor to use pattern matching:

```
factPrint :: [Int] -> IO ()
factPrint [] = putStrLn ""
factPrint list = do
  putStrLn (show.fact.head) list
  factPrint (tail list)
```

So, if factPrint returns `IO ()`, and the type of `putStrLn ""` is `IO ()`, then it's perfectly legal for `factPrint []` to equal `putStrLn ""`. No `do` required--in fact, you could just say `factPrint [] = return ()` if you didn't want the trailing newline.

Answer (score 4):

`do` is used to tie multiple monadic expressions together. It has no effect when followed by only a single expression.

For the if to be well-formed it is only necessary that the then-clause and the else-clause have the same type. Since both clauses have the type `IO ()` this is the case.

Answer (score 3):

The do keyword is used for sequencing, an if-then-else in Haskell doesn't have to contain a `do` at all if each branch is a single statement eg.

```
if a
  then b
  else c
```

You need the `do` in your example as you are sequencing two operations on your else branch.  If you omit the `do` then the `factPrint(tail list)` statement is considered to not be part of the function and thus the compiler complains as it's encountered an unexpected statement.

Comment: `do` here is _not_ a function, it is a keyword.

Comment: Similarly, `if a then b else c` and `factPrint(tail list)` are not statements, they are expressions.